# Coupon Collecting Problem: Condition on the order of coupons you see

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation, coupon-collector, expected-value

> There are four types of coupons (call them types $1,2,3,4$) with $p_1 = p_2 = 1/8$ and $p_3 = p_4 = 3/8$. You collect coupons until you have a full set.
>
> **Q1**: What is the probability that after disregarding duplicates, the order of coupons that you collect is $3241$? For example, let's say it takes you $10$ tries to get a full set and you obtain $3333324421$ which means the order of coupons collected was $3241$.
>
> **Q2**: Given that the order you observe will be $3241$ (with possible duplicates), what is the expected number of coupons needed to collect a full set?
>
> **Q3**: Let $X$ be the number of coupons needed to collect a full set. Is it true that $E[X] = E[X \mid 3241]P(3241) + E[X \mid 1234]P(1234) +...$ where you condition $X$ on all $4!$ possible ways that you will observe the order of new coupons that appear?

---

**My attempt**

**Q1:** $P(3241) = P(3)P(2 \mid 3)P(4 \mid 32)P(1 \mid 324) = \frac{3}{8}\frac{1}{5}\frac{3}{4}\frac{1}{1} = 0.05625$

**Q2:** $E[X \mid 3241] = 1+\frac{3+1}{1}+\frac{3+1+3}{3}+\frac{1+3+3+1}{1} = 15.33$ which is leveraging the EV of a geometric RV.

**Q3:** I believe yes... but when I put it in python I don't get the right answer. It could be because of my crappy scripting skills. Above in my attempt I solved for the case $3241$ and my output below matches it.

(1, 2, 3, 4) Condl EV: 7.33 | Prob: 0.0089 | EV*Prob: 0.06 | Cum Sum: 0.06

(1, 2, 4, 3) Condl EV: 7.33 | Prob: 0.0089 | EV*Prob: 0.06 | Cum Sum: 0.13

(1, 3, 2, 4) Condl EV: 10.0 | Prob: 0.0133 | EV*Prob: 0.13 | Cum Sum: 0.26

(1, 3, 4, 2) Condl EV: 12.6 | Prob: 0.0401 | EV*Prob: 0.50 | Cum Sum: 0.77

(1, 4, 2, 3) Condl EV: 10.0 | Prob: 0.0133 | EV*Prob: 0.13 | Cum Sum: 0.90

(1, 4, 3, 2) Condl EV: 12.6 | Prob: 0.0401 | EV*Prob: 0.50 | Cum Sum: 1.41

(2, 1, 3, 4) Condl EV: 7.33 | Prob: 0.0089 | EV*Prob: 0.06 | Cum Sum: 1.48

(2, 1, 4, 3) Condl EV: 7.33 | Prob: 0.0089 | EV*Prob: 0.06 | Cum Sum: 1.54

(2, 3, 1, 4) Condl EV: 10.0 | Prob: 0.0133 | EV*Prob: 0.13 | Cum Sum: 1.68

(2, 3, 4, 1) Condl EV: 12.6 | Prob: 0.0401 | EV*Prob: 0.50 | Cum Sum: 2.19

(2, 4, 1, 3) Condl EV: 10.0 | Prob: 0.0133 | EV*Prob: 0.13 | Cum Sum: 2.32

(2, 4, 3, 1) Condl EV: 12.6 | Prob: 0.0401 | EV*Prob: 0.50 | Cum Sum: 2.83

(3, 1, 2, 4) Condl EV: 12.6 | Prob: 0.0187 | EV*Prob: 0.23 | Cum Sum: 3.07

(3, 1, 4, 2) Condl EV: 15.3 | Prob: 0.0562 | EV*Prob: 0.86 | Cum Sum: 3.93

(3, 2, 1, 4) Condl EV: 12.6 | Prob: 0.0187 | EV*Prob: 0.23 | Cum Sum: 4.17

**(3, 2, 4, 1)** Condl EV: **15.3** | Prob: **0.0562** | EV*Prob: 0.86 | Cum Sum: 5.03

(3, 4, 1, 2) Condl EV: 18.0 | Prob: 0.1124 | EV*Prob: 2.02 | Cum Sum: 7.05

(3, 4, 2, 1) Condl EV: 18.0 | Prob: 0.1124 | EV*Prob: 2.02 | Cum Sum: 9.08

(4, 1, 2, 3) Condl EV: 12.6 | Prob: 0.0187 | EV*Prob: 0.23 | Cum Sum: 9.32

(4, 1, 3, 2) Condl EV: 15.3 | Prob: 0.0562 | EV*Prob: 0.86 | Cum Sum: 10.1

(4, 2, 1, 3) Condl EV: 12.6 | Prob: 0.0187 | EV*Prob: 0.23 | Cum Sum: 10.4

(4, 2, 3, 1) Condl EV: 15.3 | Prob: 0.0562 | EV*Prob: 0.86 | Cum Sum: 11.2

(4, 3, 1, 2) Condl EV: 18.0 | Prob: 0.1124 | EV*Prob: 2.02 | Cum Sum: 13.3

(4, 3, 2, 1) Condl EV: 18.0 | Prob: 0.1124 | EV*Prob: 2.02 | Cum Sum: 15.3

I get $15.3$ but the true answer is $437/35 \approx 12.48$.

Comment: Your answers to Q1 and Q2 look good.  You may want to give some more explanation  though. Q3 just looks like the law of total expectation.

Comment: @Michael Thanks for your help. For Q1 I just started from an easier question and hoped it would apply... when rolling a die the probability of seeing one of the $6!$ arrangements (ie 423156) is $\frac{1}{6}\frac{1}{5}\frac{1}{4}\frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{1}$. The answer to Q1 looks very strange to me, to see fractions like $\frac{1}{5}$ and "carve out the denominator"... but I suppose what's right is right. I feel more uneasy about Q2 and Q3. For Q2, I wonder if I am double counting and I struggle to formalize my approach to Q2, for example further conditioning on $E[X \mid 3241]$.

Comment: I do not understand your explanation of Q1.  The $3/8$ comes because you need to pick "3" first, so it is $\frac{p_3}{p_1+p_2+p_3+p_4}$.  I agree with your $1/5$, but can you explain it?  For Q2 it looks like you are using $X=X_a+X_b+X_c+X_d$ inside the conditional expectation.

Comment: You may also want to give a better example in the question since I assume $33332322444241$ also means an order of $3241$.

Comment: @Michael For Q2 thanks that helps. I was thinking I was conditioning on another event but instead it's breaking up $X$ and using LOE. For Q1 it does make sense. However what I find interesting is $P(2 \mid 3) = \frac{1}{5}$ and the way I think about it is I'm in the reduced sample space - a world where you cannot get $3$ again because it has already occured, from which $1/5$ follows. But in all worlds it seems that it's always possible to get $3$ on any given pull of the slot machine. I think I'm just tripping myself out.

Comment: @Michael yes... your example of $33332322444241$ is a good one and I believe I factored this into the answer to Q2. I will edit the OP to add this. By the way, thanks so much for looking through my thought process, I've been thinking about this problem for a few days.

Comment: The reduced sample space idea is how I also think of  it, $\frac{1}{5} = \frac{p_2}{p_2+p_4+p_1}$.  It is "reduced" since if you ever draw a "3" you can think of throwing it away and trying again. The Q3 is just the law of total expectation, but it is written in a way that seems to either trick you or tell you it is not true...the only way it is not true is if the events in question do not exhaust the sample space.  They exhaust the sample space if you consider situations like 3332322444241 (your prior example suggests you never get repetitions of an old number).

Comment: @Michael Ooooh that is a great point... in the reduced sample space you can still get $3$ at any stage but you just throw it out. I think your example which has repeats of previously collected numbers was something I wasn't thinking about enough. So when rolling a die and tracking new outcomes only, say 423156, the probability of this arrangement is $\frac{1}{6}\frac{1}{5}\frac{1}{4}\frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{1}$ where at the final stage (trying to get a 6) all outcomes are still equally possible but the probability that the next new outcome being 6 must be $1$.

Comment: I thought I was living in some world where the dice turns to be one sided or something and you could only roll a 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your calculation of the conditional expectations is wrong – though I must admit it seemed plausible to me at first and I had to write a simulation to pinpoint the mistake.

To see why it can't be right, consider three types of coupons with probabilities $p_1\gg p_2\gg p_3$ arriving in the order $231$. The way you're calculating the conditional expectation for the $3$ to appear, you're ignoring coupons of type $1$ and assuming that as long as you know that $3$ is next to appear, you can treat the process as if only types $2$ and $3$ existed, leading to the expectation $\frac{p_2+p_3}{p_3}$. But that's a large number, whereas if $3$ comes before $1$ it's most likely to come right away, so the expectation should be close to $1$.

Once $2$ has appeared, the expected time to see the next new type is $\frac1{1-p_2}=\frac1{p_1+p_3}$, and this is independent of whether that next new type happens to be $1$ or $3$: If you calculate the conditional expectation the pedestrian way as

$$
\frac{\sum_nnp_2^np_3}{\sum_np_2^np_3}\;,
$$

$p_3$ drops out. So

$$
\mathsf E[X\mid3241]=1+\frac85+2+8=12.6\;,
$$

and if you do them all like that, the answer comes out right.

Comment: Woot woot! Thanks for figuring out what was wrong. This has been in the back of my mind for days. Thinking of an extreme example ($p_1\gg p_2\gg p_3$) is helpful... if you ever start a cult like Pythagoras and need a lazy disciple that doesn't follow orders or attend meetings and has no resources let me know.